# Javascript: this is undefined inside jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, this

```js
$('.myclass').click(() => {
  let myvar = this;
  console.log(this.tagName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><button class="myclass">click me</button></li>
```

Output in the console is `undefined`, but I expected button? I need a data-* attribute from that button (you're looking at reduced/minimalized code), but I cannot even grab the element via `this` - why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the click handler `this` referes to window object. So `this.tagName` is undefined. To access that element you should use event's target.

```
$('.myclass').click((e) => {
  console.log(e.target.tagName);
})
```

If you want to access data attribute then you can wrap `e.target` with jQuery and use data function for same.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><button class="myclass" data-id="1">click me</button></li>
```

The javascript code to get data-id is.

```
$('.myclass').click((e) => {
  console.log($(e.target).data('id'));
})
```

Comment: Arguably... id say using the event object is the better solution compared to not using an arrow function simply to avoid ambiguity, but it'd be useful if your answer at least addressed the reason `this` refers to the window object and not the clicked element as shown in the documentation. (it also may not even refer to window! depending on where the given code was ran.)